# Drupal 7, form submit: Display result of a query?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, form-api

Using the form api, I'm to display the result of some processing after a post is sent by a form.

So I implement the module_name_submit(...) method:

```
function cmis_views_block_view($delta = '') {

    $cmisview = cmis_views_load($delta);
    $block['content'] = cmis_views_info($cmisview);
    return $block;
}
```

The processing is very simple. The call happens properly and I would like to display the $block on screen.
Returning this doesn't help. Maybe a redirect could help, but I'm looking first for something equivalent to drupal_set_message() but that dispays html in the page.

Any leads welcome :-)
Thanks,
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the content in a session variable, redirect to that page and have a custom block output that specific variable in the $content

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `$form_state['redirect']`